# UITapGesture for Button are working. But, long press gesture for the same are not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

> I have a table view with X number of rows.
>
> One of the row has collection view inside it.
>
> Collection view has Y number of cells.
>
> Every cell has a button.

**Now, the problem is; If I apply a tap gesture for button inside the collection view cell it works.
But, when I apply a long press gesture to button it is not working at all.**

Following is the code that I am trying.

```
-(void)setupGestureForAllButton{
    for (UIButton *button in self.keyboardButtons) {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
        [gr addTarget:self action:@selector(userLongPressed:)];
        [button addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    }
}
- (void)userLongPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"user long pressed");
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Please find the pictorial representation of the problem
[image]

**UPDATE 1 :**

setting `gr.delegate = self;` did the trick.

I am still not sure; then, why it was working for tap gesture in the first place.

Comment: You can try with `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`

Comment: setting gr.delegate = self; did the trick :)